# Autocomplete in Data Grid MUI - Editing (On pressing Spacebar, Screen scrolls down)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

Trying to implement this feature in one of my web application having datagrid component. It has Autocomplete in one cell. When user has searched with some keyword and if that keyword has space between two charecters, it scrolls down to last sell right now which is not an expected behaviour. Expected behaviour should be it should allow user to put space between two characters while searching. Here is the example code.

```
const columns = [
  {
    field: "SUPPLIER_NORM_NAME",
    headerName: "Supplier Norm Name",
    sortable: false,
    width: 325,
  },
  {
    field: "OVERRIDE_SUPPLIER_NORM_NAME",
    headerName: "Override Supplier Norm Name",
    // editable: true,
    width: 450,
    renderCell: (params) => {
      console.log("PARAMS NORM", params);
      return (
        <TextDrop
          inputValue={inputValue}
          setInputValue={setInputValue}
          id={params.id}
          gridNorm={gridNorm}
        />
      );
    },
  },
];

<DataGrid
  columns={columns}
  onRowClick={handleRowClick}
  // other props
/>

{/* TextDrop Component */}
<Autocomplete
  sx={{ padding: "0px !important " }}
  value={inputValue[id] ? inputValue[id] : null}
  fullWidth
  options={options?.map((i) => i?.SUPPLIER_NORM_NAME)}
  noOptionsText="Enter to create a new"
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
  onInputChange={(e, newValue) => {
    setInputValue((old) => {
      return {
        ...old,
        [id]: newValue,
      };
    });
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      sx={{ padding: "0px !important " }}
      fullWidth
      value={inputValue[id]}
      onChange={(e) =>
        setInputValue((old) => {
          return {
            ...old,
            [id]: e.target.value,
          };
        })
      }
      {...params}
      // other props
    />
  )}
/>
```

[image]

I have tried to use MUI Datagrid component with Autocomplete. I was expecting that user should be allowed to put space between characters but right now, it scrolls down while pressing space key. If I set editable to true, Autocomplete component gets override with TextField.